# Mount LVM to recover data: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on

Tags: mount, lvm, proxmox

How do i mount lvm disk used by VM on host machine (Proxmox), so i can copy files?

The VM (Xpenology) is broken and I can't boot on it anymore. I had 2 4TB disk in RAID 1 mounted on it and I want to get back my data but I can't mount the LVM.

(I'm only interested in Disk_1 and Disk_2)

Here are some info:

```
root@pr0xm0x:~# lvs
  LV            VG     Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  vm-100-disk-0 Disk_1 -wi-a-----    3.55t
  vm-100-disk-0 Disk_2 -wi-a-----    3.55t
  data          pve    twi-aotz-- <181.69g             66.51  3.92
  root          pve    -wi-ao----   69.50g
  swap          pve    -wi-ao----    8.00g
  vm-100-disk-0 pve    Vwi-a-tz--   16.00g data        12.24
  vm-100-disk-1 pve    Vwi-a-tz--   52.00m data        57.21
  vm-103-disk-1 pve    Vwi-a-tz--    6.00g data        27.56
  vm-200-disk-0 pve    Vwi-a-tz--  120.00g data        97.66
  vm-200-disk-1 pve    Vwi-a-tz--  100.00g data        0.00



root@pr0xm0x:~# parted /dev/Disk_1/vm-100-disk-0 print
Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/dm-0: 3908GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2551MB  2550MB  ext4                  raid
 2      2551MB  4699MB  2147MB  linux-swap(v1)        raid
 3      4832MB  3908GB  3903GB                        raid



root@pr0xm0x:~# lsblk
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0 279.4G  0 disk
├─sda1                          8:1    0  1007K  0 part
├─sda2                          8:2    0   512M  0 part
└─sda3                          8:3    0 278.9G  0 part
  ├─pve-swap                  253:2    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─pve-root                  253:3    0  69.5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─pve-data_tmeta            253:4    0   1.9G  0 lvm
  │ └─pve-data-tpool          253:6    0 181.7G  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-data              253:7    0 181.7G  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-vm--200--disk--0  253:8    0   120G  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-vm--100--disk--0  253:9    0    16G  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-vm--100--disk--1  253:10   0    52M  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-vm--200--disk--1  253:11   0   100G  0 lvm
  │   └─pve-vm--103--disk--1  253:12   0     6G  0 lvm
  └─pve-data_tdata            253:5    0 181.7G  0 lvm
    └─pve-data-tpool          253:6    0 181.7G  0 lvm
      ├─pve-data              253:7    0 181.7G  0 lvm
      ├─pve-vm--200--disk--0  253:8    0   120G  0 lvm
      ├─pve-vm--100--disk--0  253:9    0    16G  0 lvm
      ├─pve-vm--100--disk--1  253:10   0    52M  0 lvm
      ├─pve-vm--200--disk--1  253:11   0   100G  0 lvm
      └─pve-vm--103--disk--1  253:12   0     6G  0 lvm
sdb                             8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─Disk_2-vm--100--disk--0     253:1    0   3.6T  0 lvm
sdc                             8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─Disk_1-vm--100--disk--0     253:0    0   3.6T  0 lvm
  ├─Disk_1-vm--100--disk--0p1 253:13   0   2.4G  0 part
  ├─Disk_1-vm--100--disk--0p2 253:14   0     2G  0 part
  └─Disk_1-vm--100--disk--0p3 253:15   0   3.6T  0 part
sdd                             8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk
sde                             8:64   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sde1                          8:65   0   1.8T  0 part
sdf                             8:80   1  14.4G  0 disk
├─sdf1                          8:81   1   2.9G  0 part
├─sdf2                          8:82   1   3.9M  0 part
└─sdf3                          8:83   1  11.6G  0 part
sr0                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

root@pr0xm0x:~# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/Disk_1/vm-100-disk-0
  LV Name                vm-100-disk-0
  VG Name                Disk_1
  LV UUID                Hek0vC-VCjH-9BhS-i1Va-5X3d-0mzC-FK3bbM
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pr0xm0x, 2020-01-23 08:50:40 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 3
  LV Size                3.55 TiB
  Current LE             931840
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/Disk_2/vm-100-disk-0
  LV Name                vm-100-disk-0
  VG Name                Disk_2
  LV UUID                M6dzfZ-6wXt-dyvI-pSL8-3hky-aROy-JfWZUC
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pr0xm0x, 2020-01-23 08:50:55 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                3.55 TiB
  Current LE             931840
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                JogsLv-1xic-2cK2-rBRX-EHt5-buYg-pcrWJM
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2019-12-07 11:10:23 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                Ukw2fX-Dcf1-RueD-mx6e-spEw-GdrV-fvxnjB
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2019-12-07 11:10:23 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                69.50 GiB
  Current LE             17792
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:3

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                data
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                LZmHdO-0rZX-XfGy-6fRz-j9bm-VmJz-yS2CQd
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2019-12-07 11:10:24 +0100
  LV Pool metadata       data_tmeta
  LV Pool data           data_tdata
  LV Status              available
  # open                 6
  LV Size                <181.69 GiB
  Allocated pool data    66.51%
  Allocated metadata     3.92%
  Current LE             46512
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:6

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/vm-200-disk-0
  LV Name                vm-200-disk-0
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                vRF4uB-WzMy-B2Nm-LDcy-T8BN-ghjF-PqPVKS
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pr0xm0x, 2019-12-17 11:03:55 +0100
  LV Pool name           data
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                120.00 GiB
  Mapped size            97.66%
  Current LE             30720
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:8

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/vm-100-disk-0
  LV Name                vm-100-disk-0
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                3yGcBF-rhHJ-EMhC-Ft8o-okne-YdVg-ll3D4f
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pr0xm0x, 2020-01-23 08:40:48 +0100
  LV Pool name           data
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                16.00 GiB
  Mapped size            12.24%
  Current LE             4096
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:9

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/vm-100-disk-1
  LV Name                vm-100-disk-1
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                3YV9J4-mLv3-yHg3-Sv2f-kklP-cvPt-1H5Zc0
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pr0xm0x, 2020-01-23 08:48:19 +0100
  LV Pool name           data
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                52.00 MiB
  Mapped size            57.21%
  Current LE             13
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:10

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/vm-200-disk-1
  LV Name                vm-200-disk-1
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                3TWqbr-RO52-chRo-ubLf-zzzx-4QGg-Z21cuq
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pr0xm0x, 2020-02-01 13:59:13 +0100
  LV Pool name           data
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                100.00 GiB
  Mapped size            0.00%
  Current LE             25600
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:11

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/vm-103-disk-1
  LV Name                vm-103-disk-1
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                4e22Xm-P40c-NaxA-TttF-5eBQ-F3CR-IcK2DP
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pr0xm0x, 2022-01-30 16:47:57 +0100
  LV Pool name           data
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                6.00 GiB
  Mapped size            27.56%
  Current LE             1536
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:12
```

And here is the result of mount:

```
root@pr0xm0x:~# mount /dev/Disk_1/vm-100-disk-0 /mnt/Disk_1/
mount: /mnt/Disk_1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/Disk_1-vm--100--disk--0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Comment: [this](https://backdrift.org/mounting-a-file-system-on-a-partition-inside-of-an-lvm-volume)?

Comment: @Bravo It helps and I finally can access my files! Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it!

Comment: I removed "SOLVED" from the title. Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names of the logical volumes suggest that the LVs are being used as *virtual disks* for the VMs, so each LV may contain a partition table and one or more partitions - and your `parted` output proves that's exactly what is happening.

You won't be able to directly mount `/dev/Disk_1/vm-100-disk-0` any more than you could mount `/dev/sda` when it has partitions defined. When you mount something, the filesystem driver expects the actual filesystem to begin from the very first block of the device you're trying to mount, not at some distance into the device (i.e. after the partition table and possibly other partitions).

First, use `losetup -f`: it will report the first unused `/dev/loopN` device. Use the actual device reported by this command in place of `/dev/loopN` in any subsequent commands.

Bind the LV to the loop device and request `losetup` to auto-create partition devices for it:

```
losetup -P /dev/loopN /dev/Disk_1/vm-100-disk-0
```

This will create devices like `/dev/loopNp1`, `/dev/loopNp2` etc., through which you will be able to access each individual partition of the virtual disk contained in the LV.

(If you have an old version of `losetup` that won't recognize the `-P` option, the command `kpartx` can be used as a substitute, as suggested by Bravo in the comments. Depending on your distro, `kpartx` may be available as a separate package or packaged together with `device-mapper-multipath` tools.)

If the virtual disk contains regular partitions, you should now be able to just mount them. But if the virtual disk also contains LVM physical volumes, you will have to activate the LVM volume group before you can access its LVs: `vgchange -ay` should be enough to activate any and all detectable LVM volume groups.

When you're done accessing the virtual disk, remember to undo any steps you needed to access its partitions in the proper order:

1. unmount any partitions/LVs you mounted from the virtual disk
2. if the virtual disk contained LVM volumes, deactivate any LVM volume groups you activated with `vgchange -an <name of the VG>`. If you are unsure of the name of the volume group, the output of the `pvs` command should be helpful.
3. if you used `kpartx`, run `kpartx -d /dev/loopN` to delete the partition devices as a separate step.
4. use `losetup -d /dev/loopN` to unbind the loop device (and any partition devices created by `losetup -P`).

Never leave a VM's virtual disk mounted to the host system like this while you actually run the virtual machine the disk belongs to: that would make the filesystem caches of the host and the VM go out of sync and into conflict with each other, leading rapidly to data corruption on the virtual disk.